# Incorrect Parameter when associating many Jobs to an IO completion port

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, jobs, io-completion-ports

Consider the following:

```
void SomeClass::associateCompletionPort(HANDLE hJob) {
  JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT jacp = { 0 };
  jacp.CompletionKey = hJob;
  jacp.CompletionPort = hCompletionPort;

  if (!SetInformationJobObject(
    hJob,
    JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation,
    &jacp,
    sizeof(jacp))) {
    // open a 'pop-up' with an error message, of the last error encountered.
    dumpLastError(TEXT("SetInformationJobObject"));
  }
}
```

1.`hCompletionPort` is initialized, in the constructor of `SomeClass`, like this:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() : 
  hCompletionPort(CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1)) {
  if (!hCompletionPort) {
    dumpLastError(TEXT("CreateIoCompletionPort"));
  }
}
```

2.`hJob` is an HANDLE to a Job Object that "contains" just one Process;
3.This method is called for multiple Job Objects, therefore there is a one-to-many mapping when it comes to associating Jobs to the Completion Port;

*Note: This is part of some code I use to get messages everytime a certain limit is exceeded / broken, later on.*

I test this by launching the processes in question (confined to one Job Object each) before this particular snippet is run.

### The Problem:

Everytime a Job Object is to be associated with the Completion Port, the association fails with:

> SetInformationJobObject failed with error 87; The parameter is
>   incorrect.

But the most awkward thing is that in some rare occasions, everything works fine. I can confirm this because I get the messages I was expecting in some other part of the code, where I call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`.

For instance, when I first ran this a few hours ago, everything worked as expected. But after that, it always threw the same error message and, of course, I never caught messages of limits being broken.

Comment: That code looks fine; I have essentially identical code and it works.  Can you show the code that creates the completion port, and also the code that creates the job object, assigns the process to it, and then calls `associateCompletionPort` ?

Comment: That piece of code you ask -- where the job is created and the process associated to it -- is done externally, in another executable to which I do not have the code. Sorry. I just know some details of process assignment to jobs, because I've enumerated the handles of each process, I'm interested in. I've edited the post, including the completion port creation. Are there any details regarding job creation and process assignment to jobs that could interfere with `associateCompletionPort`? Thank you!

Comment: The most obvious possible cause is that the code that creates the job has already associated it with a completion port; according to the documentation, a job can only be associated with a completion port once.

Comment: That is, probably, the worst case scenario, since I cannot `QueryInformationJobObject` to access completion ports... But that's alright, I have no fear. I will look into it and I'll post further if I solve this problem. Thank you very much!